# Netbeans still showing root folder

Tags: codeigniter, .htaccess, netbeans

I'm starting a new Codeigniter project inside of Netbeans 7.3.1 and have the following set up for my file structure.

I have in the project properties set up as the web root is pointed to public_html inside of the text box. I also have this for my htaccess file as well as I have removed index.php from the ci config file.

My problem is that when I go to localhost/MyProject it still shows the foot folder and I don't know why.

Is there anyone that sees a mistake I have made somewhere.

```
-root
    -application
    -system
    -public_html
        -assets
        .htaccess
        index.php

Options -Indexes
Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

#Removes access to the system folder by users.
#Additionally this will allow you to create a System.php controller,

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]

#When your application folder isn't in the system folder

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

#Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file,
#such as an image or css document, if this isn't true it sends the
#request to index.php

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]

# If we don't have mod_rewrite installed, all 404's
# can be sent to index.php, and everything works as normal.
# Submitted by: ElliotHaughin   

ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
```

Comment: I think you or Netbeans got confused during the project setup phase, probably when the [run configuration](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/php/project-setup.html#runConfiguration) was setup.  It exposes its project directory, which is obviously not what should be happening.

Comment: That could be because I first made the project and then went in and started moving things around and making new folders. Are you saying that I need to fix the index file input box for this problem?

Comment: See the run configuration page I linked to, it explains all the different options.

Comment: have you changed your base_url ?

Comment: @fvu I looked at the run configuration and I don't see anything that would cause an issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Out of the box Netbeans doesn't come with CodeIgniter support, but that can easily be solved by installing the appropriate plugin:

https://kenai.com/projects/nbphpci/pages/Home

Due to the specific structure of a CodeIgniter project telling Netbeans that a CodeIgniter project is just another php project won't work correctly.

The detailed procedure to install this plugin can be found on [their Wiki](https://kenai.com/projects/nbphpci/pages/NBInstall) or [here](http://alielwafdy.wordpress.com/2012/07/28/codeigniter-support-in-netbeans/).  Usage is explained [here](https://kenai.com/projects/nbphpci/pages/Home).

I think that you will have to restart a new project and properly activate CodeIgniter support in the project setup wizard, and that should be it.

Comment: As this is a good answer. For some reason I don't think that will necessarily solve my issue.

Comment: Just my two cents, Im not superbly familiar with NetBeans, but CI I am.. based on the directory structure he added, take note that its not your common CI layout either seeing as app and sys are outside of the root public html folder

Comment: @chris I'm quite familiar with NB but not with CI, I can merely point out that 1) OP seems to not have the CI plugin installed 2) NB seems to be confused about the project directory layout.  public_html was if I read OP's question correctly through netbeans, which by combining 1 and 2 may very well have ended up in the "wrong" spot.  That's why I believe that it's a good idea to install the plugin, start over with a new project with CI support enabled and see what happens.

Comment: I attempted it and then went to do a new project and I'm having some issues. I selected the php interpreter must be selected as an error when I select the framework so it gives me that error.

Comment: @user2576961 I have no idea what you're talking about...  What error?